# Is this a Symbol or a Font; and How to Reproduce?

Tags: fonts, symbols, typography, latin

In typesetting some Latin footnotes, I have come across this rather unusual depiction of *ff*:

[image]

The double *f* looks to me like some type of a special symbol; but, I am wondering if it is the result of the font used.

Can the displayed *double f* (symbol) be reproduced in Latex? Thank you.

Comment: This is called a 'ligature', two consecutive f's are combined. LaTeX does this automatically, try for example `\textit{Ineffabilis}`.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you for telling me what it is called. Before posting the question, I had tried the `\textit` as you suggest---but it does not produce the same "symbol-like" effect. Perhaps it is a combination of the `\textit` command with some particular font.

Comment: Yes, ligatures look different depending on the typeface, as do the separate glyphs, and some typefaces are designed to work without ligatures.

Comment: The spacing in this word looks like it was input in math mode.  But the italic alphabet used for math shouldn't have an "ff" ligature.  So, in order for us to figure out what is happening, we really need to know how this was input.  Perhaps letterspacing lhas been applied?

Comment: Is your goal to reproduce the source text as closely as possible, including the exact positioning of the characters? In that case I would advise against this, first because it is very hard to do and second because it is not particularly readable (also the `il` combination is problematic in that regard). If your concern is that the source uses a symbol so you also want that same symbol: it's not really a symbol, it is still two f's but they are put closely together, which you can do in several ways (only the middle connected as in LaTeX or also the top and bottom connected as in the source).